# can not ping from remote host over raspberry pi router

Tags: networking, wifi, access-point

Going through [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point in a standalone network (NAT)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) I set up Raspberry pi as access point  as standalone NAT with out bridging. wireless host is connected but cant ping directly to Raspberry pi router. Any suggestion please