# ssh working but i can't ping directly to the Raspberry pi router

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi, access-point

Going through https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md i set up Raspberry pi as access point as standalone NAT with out bridging. wireless host is connected but cant ping but i can ssh directly to Raspberry pi router. Any suggestion please.
RPI Router -

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf
  interface wlan0
  static ip_address=10.42.0.11/24
        nohook wpa_supplicant

sudo nano /etc/dnsmasq.conf 


interface=wlan0  
dhcp-range=10.42.0.15,10.42.0.19,255.255.255.0,24h
```

In mac book PC i can get -

```
IP Address 10.42.0.19
subnet mask 255.255.255.0
Router 10.42.0.11
```

Comment: You can edit your question, no need to ask the same question again, https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89859/can-not-ping-from-remote-host-over-raspberry-pi-router